# Drupal Country-City multiple dropdown ajax enabled?

Tags: drupal, field, dropbox

I'm looking for a country-city like field for Drupal 7. If the user changed the value in dropdown box A, values changes in dropbox B.

Please help

Thanks
Abbas

Answer (score 1):

Download the [examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples), there's a module called `ajax_example` which shows you exactly how to do do it.